# What is this MediaPlayback Error in iOS with Capacitor?

Tags: ios, capacitor

I do get this in Xcode while running in the simulator:

```
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x600002981c20; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x7fbe0f927ed0; requestedReason: MediaPlayback; reason: MediaPlayback; flags: PreventTaskSuspend | PreventTaskThrottleDown | WantsForegroundResourcePriority>;
    }
}
```

My audio is running. But would like to know, what causes this and how to fix it.